# ImportError: No module named Quandl

Tags: quandl

No module named `Quandl` in my Python version `2.7` please help.

How do i fix this issue even I can see this in my pip list `Quandl` is there.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `import quandl`, per the [Quandl python docs](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python#retrieving-data).